# JQuery data grid with sort, items, columns drag&drop. Is there any?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, editing, html-table

jQuery data grid with items&columns drag&drop, Items sort. Is there any?

I need:

- Dragable\Dropable Items
- Drag and drop sorting of table columns
- Sort Items in columns

You can experience the usefulness of Adobe Flex builder Data Grid and its Drag-Drop [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/19/dragging-rows-between-two-different-flex-datagrid-controls/):

Is there any jQuery analog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jqGrid has drag & drop functionality - is this what you're looking for?

Check out the [jqGrid demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), under "New in Version 3.6" -> "Drag & Drop Rows"